# Yolo training displays Wrong annotaion: x = 0,y = 0

Tags: python, dataset, yolo, darknet

I am training a hand detector in yolo. I downloaded the OID dataset and converted labels into .txt files. There is no classes.txt file in the obj folder where all these image and txt files are located.

The following colab notebook is training butt during training it shows following error.

> 71: 1103.611938, 1592.691406 avg loss, 0.000000 rate, 50.474687
> seconds, 4544 images, 34.616345 hours left Loaded: 0.000100 seconds
>
> Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file:
> data/obj/2933ef25f4c578ee.txt
>
> Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file:
> data/obj/09848088f423c5ce.txt
>
> Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file:
> data/obj/c21c73b84a01595c.txt
>
> Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file:
> data/obj/9ee7440dbe46b8f8.txt
>
> Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file:
> data/obj/09848088f423c5ce.txt  v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75,
> obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 82 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1,
> class_loss = 175.932907, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 175.932907
> v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 94
> Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 538.309937, iou_loss =
> 0.000000, total_loss = 538.309937
>
> Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file:
> data/obj/b8294ff3c2be6fbe.txt
>
> Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file:
> data/obj/9ee7440dbe46b8f8.txt
>
> Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1, file:
> data/obj/a94e1658b7d9ff0a.txt

Link to my colab notebook.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1p1rtNUACaGWve3lqdz8fe0gEYPkSNzWe?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i have changed can you help

Answer (score 1):

Let's review YOLO's bounding box label format, and refer to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIrBf.jpg) as a reference:

> ```
> <class id> <Xo/X> <Yo/Y> <W/X> <H/Y>
> ```

Where:

```
<class id>, label index of the class, integer object number from 0 to (classes-1)
<Xo/X>, coordinate of the bounding box’s center
<Yo/Y>, coordinate of the bounding box’s center
W, Width of the bounding box
H, Height of the bounding box
X, Width of the image
Y, Height of the image
```

Now, you have the error:

```
Wrong annotation: x = 0, y = 0, < 0 or > 1
```

In other words, it means `<Xo/X> = 0, <Yo/Y> = 0, < 0 or > 1`

This means that a part of your labels are outside the borders of your images.

Please inspect your images with "bad" labels at `bad_label.list`

Answer (score 0):

i am facing the same issue previous 2 months.
Reason:
i am doing wrong annotation,values of x and y should be between 0 and 1.
Solution:
I was using bbox tool to annotate my dataset but this gives an error but now i am using makesense.ai which gives normalize values and my error is resoved now.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30963747)